# How can I name elements in a list and replace them?

Tags: python-2.7

I have two list and I want to check if list`b` is subordinate to list`a`

```
a = [['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
b = ['2', '1']
```

So I tried following code:

```
for element in b:
    checklist = []
    parts = element.split(',')
    for x in a:
        if set(b).issubset(set(x)) is True:
            check.append(x)
```

this works! but it will output:

```
[['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

what I want is make output like:

```
[1, 3] or [a, c]    -----------1 and a stand for['1', '2']；3 and c stand for['1', '2', '3']
```

because this is only a short example here(I got a more complex `a` in fact...), so I tend to use loop to make it work...any idea? Thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work it out following code hope can help:

```
nodeNo = []
for value in checklist:
    for position, item in enumerate(a):
        if item == value:
            nodeNo.append(position+1)
list2 = ['NO{0}'.format(i) for i in nodeNo]
print list2
```

Hope can help who need it. thanks anyway